# create a regex that reads wordpress like patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to read a series of parameters from a url that comes like /name/value

this is the regex I have so far, but it only catches the last pair of parameters.
how can I catch the whole set of parameters in a group ? (a, b, c)

demo:

http://regex101.com/r/zN7jU2/2

regex:
`\/controller\/action((\/(\w+)\/([\w\=]+))*)`

test urls:

`/controller/action/a/10/b/79/c/34
/controller/action`

Comment: Why regex?  Why not simple string manipulation like `split()` or a parsing approach?

Comment: because I'm using pagejs and it accepts regex in its routing function. https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js#matching-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be wanting:

```
/controller/action((?:/\w+/\w+)+)?
```

which is:

- `/controller/action`
- `((?:/\w+/\w+)+)?` - capture group $1, zero or one time, everything is captured into this
- `(?:/\w+/\w+)+` - non capture group for name/value pairs, repeated one or more times, this repeats the pattern inside this group and gives it back to the outer capturing group $1.
- `/\w+/\w+` - pattern to test for, adapt this for your needs

And if all went well you'll end up with `/a/10/b/79/c/34` in `$1`

Comment: thanks, is there any way to get an array of pairs like [['a',10], ['b',79], ['c',34]] ?

Comment: I had thought that's what you were trying, however js doesn't support things like recursion. you could use `split` then you know `name` will be even like `s[0]` or `s[2]`, and the `values` will be odd as in `s[1]` or `s[3]`. I think that's the best you'll get out of js regex though